# Failed to understand how this destructuring assignment works "{ theme : {spacing} }"

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I'm trying to override the default theme in material ui v5, at first i used this :

```
      styleOverrides:{
        root: ({ theme }) => ({
          margin : theme.spacing(2)
        }),
      },
```

But then when reading the docs i saw they used this :

```
const lightTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiPaper: {
      styleOverrides:{
        root: ({ theme : {spacing} }) => ({
          margin : spacing(2)
        }),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here i think they destructured the the spacing function from the theme object, what i dont understand is the syntax, why not do this :

```
root: ({ {spacing} }) => ({
          margin : spacing(2)
        }),
```

Where `{spacing}` is like taking out the spacing() from the `theme` object, no ?

The ":" in `{ theme : {spacing} }` is what confuses me, i'm not familiar with that syntax and i dont want to make assumptions on what it precisely does, i read these 2 resources

- [es6 in depth destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)
- [Destructuring assignment - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

But i still couldn't find the anwer, if someone could explain it i'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter likely looks like `{ theme: { spacing: ... } }`, therefore to access it you need to define the full path (theme and spacing). If you only use `({ {spacing} })` it won't know that you want to access the `spacing` within the `theme` property. For instance in the following example `({ {spacing} })` would be ambiguous, potentially meaning two different functions:

```js
const params = {
  theme: {
    spacing: (n) => `some css: ${n}`
  },
  otherProps: {
    spacing: (n) => `other prop: ${n}`
  },
}

const v1 = (params) => params.theme.spacing(2)
const v2 = ({ theme }) => theme.spacing(2)
const v3 = ({ theme: { spacing } }) => spacing(2)

console.log(v1(params))
console.log(v2(params))
console.log(v3(params))
```

Answer (score 2):

`{ {spacing} }` won't do the trick. `{ theme: {spacing} }` destructures *two* objects. First the object that is passed to the arrow function, then another object that is stored in the `.theme` property. In only variable that's being created here is `spacing`, which is `.theme.spacing`. Take this example:

```js
const obj = {theme: {spacing: 1, color: 'blue'}};

const fn1 = ({theme: {spacing}}) => console.log(spacing);
fn1(obj);
```